# php file uploading and nessecary permissions for the uploads folder (PHP/Apache)

Tags: php, apache, security, upload, chmod

To upload a file with move_uploaded_file i need to make the uploads/ folder to be chmod 777 . What are the risks of doing this. I only allow mp3 files to be uploaded. And if i were to not restrict it to only mp3s and allow all then what would be the risks and what might be the best chmod for the folder. Any recommendatins for makeing a secure uploading system would be welcome, im a noob.

I use Apache, in the config file for Apache it sais that the user "http" and group "http" are the ones that run the apache http , but when i do : ps -ef|grep apache , it shows the user as me (my personal user) , maybe because i start the apache http deamon with sudo (sudo systemctl start httpd)? the folder is chown by me also( my personal user).

i read many questions about this but none were usefull they seemed to skip over what the exact security issues might be, and if they are mittigated by restricting file mime type.

Comment: The question is, why do you have to use `chmod 777`? Normally, only the user running the web server (which indeed should be namend `http` or `apache` in your case) should need write access to that folder. IMHO, that's the thing you should figure out - why your apache is running with another user account. Perhaps you could post the whole output of the dubious `ps` command? And the according sections of your apache config.

Comment: pance      34354   34340  0 10:06 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache  (pance is my personal user)...

Comment: i assume this is the lines you are reffering to

<IfModule unixd_module>

#

# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run

# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  

#

# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.

# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for

# running httpd, as with most system services.

#

User http

Group http



</IfModule>
 i tryed to stop the process and systemctl start httpd (without sudo this time) , but pance is still the user

Comment: What you see here as `pance 34354 34340 0 10:06 pts/2 00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache` is just the grep command you started to find the apache processes! It has been started by you, therefore `pance` is the correct user. There should be more lines containing `apache`, having the correct user. The portion of the config file you posted seems fine to me. In the future, please edit your original question to add such details and use the formatting possibilities we provide. :)